# Recursive query in SQL

Tags: mysql

[image: database structure]

```
SELECT 
    p.*, 
    MIN(wp.price * (1 + wpe.addition / 100) * (1 + IFNULL(wpc.addition, 0) / 100)) AS minimal_price,
    COUNT(p.id) AS total_found
FROM products AS p
JOIN warehouses_products AS wp
    ON p.id=wp.product_id
JOIN warehouses_permissions AS wpe 
    ON wpe.warehouse_id=wp.warehouse_id
LEFT JOIN warehouses_permissions_categories AS wpc 
    ON wpc.warehouse_permission_id=wpe.id
WHERE wpe.user_id=1 AND (wpc.id IS NULL OR wpc.category_id=p.category_id)
GROUP BY p.id
```

---

**Question:** How should I modify my database structure and query if I want to add this feature: users could have "shared" warehouses - warehouse which has products from given warehouse_permission.

- User[1]: Warehouse[1] with products --> Permission[1] for Warehouse[1] for User[2] with addition[1]
- User[2]: Able to see Warehouse[1] with addition[1] | Warehouse[2] "shared" from Permission[1] -> Permission[2] for Warehouse[2] for User[2] width addition[2]
- User[3]: Able to see Warehouse[2] width addition[1]*addition[2]

Recursion begins if want to share shared warehouse.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. That would be an `OUTER JOIN`. There are two types: `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`. Like the `INNER` keyword, the `OUTER` keyword is optional. For every `LEFT JOIN` there is a logically equivalent `RIGHT JOIN`. In consequence, `RIGHT JOIN`s are vanishingly rare. By way of example compare search results for `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` on SO.
2. See above

Comment: I know about OUTER JOINS but still can not figure out how to get wanted results

Answer (score 0):

I would merge warehouses_permissions & warehouse_permissions_categories would solve most of the issues. If needed later you can divide or come up with other structure.